# Program prints menu twice in a row

Tags: java

I'm making a credential like program and it is very WIP. I placed a while loop with a Boolean condition to make the program run again whenever a person finishes creating a credential, but when it loops to the beginning of the program it prints the first part twice! like this:

```
run:
     |-----------------------------------------------|
     |Welcome to the Credential Managing System 2013!|
     |-----------------------------------------------|

      Would you like to create or manage a credential?

                 Choose: Manage | Create

                    Waiting for input: Create

Credential name: df
Credential ID: 34243
Credential Password: numbers or words?
Waiting for input: numbers
Credential Password: 13651

                      |-------------------|
                      |Credential created!|
                      |-------------------|




      Would you like to create or manage a credential?

                 Choose: Manage | Create

                    Waiting for input:
```

from there it stops reading the input again.

here is the entire code!

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Carlinhos
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Criação {

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);



System.out.println("         |-----------------------------------------------|");
System.out.println("         |Welcome to the Credential Managing System 2013!|");
System.out.println("         |-----------------------------------------------|");
System.out.println("");

Boolean autoRun = true;

while(autoRun){

System.out.println("          Would you like to create or manage a credential?");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("                     Choose: Manage | Create");
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("                        Waiting for input: ");

String op1 = e.nextLine();
autoRun = false;

if(op1.equals("Create")){

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Credential name: ");
    String credName = e.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Credential ID: ");
    int credID = e.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Credential Password: numbers or words?");
    System.out.print("Waiting for input: ");
    e.nextLine();
    String credPassCheck = e.nextLine();

    if(credPassCheck.equals("numbers")){

        System.out.print("Credential Password: ");
        double credPassNum = e.nextDouble();
        }

    else if(credPassCheck.equals("words")){

        System.out.print("Credential Password: ");
        String credPassLet = e.nextLine();
        }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("                          |-------------------|");
    System.out.println("                          |Credential created!|");
    System.out.println("                          |-------------------|");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");

    autoRun = true;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A lot of people on SO are multilingual. Having your error messages in  portuguese is fine as long as you understand the answer :) See my answer below and accept it by clicking on the white tick mark next to it.

Comment: i would check off it if it worked perfectly well. I could translate it for the forums if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
while(autoRun = true)
```

to this:

```
while(autoRun)
```

`=` is not the equality comparison operator, it's the assignment operator. So, when you check that condition `autoRun` is the assigned the value `true` even though you set it to `false` earlier. You can use `==` instead but since autoRun is a boolean variable, you can simply use this variable without comparing it to anything else.

**UPDATE**:

After OP's comments that the program has started exiting after printing the prompt for the second time, I looked into the code a little more and found these lines:

```
if(credPassCheck.equals("numbers")){
    System.out.print("Credential Password: ");
    double credPassNum = e.nextDouble();
}
```

This is basically consuming less input than is necessary and thus the next prompt for "Waiting for Input" gets a single newline character as its input. The fix should be obvious now:

```
if(credPassCheck.equals("numbers")){
    System.out.print("Credential Password: ");
    double credPassNum = e.nextDouble();
    e.nextLine(); //Add this Line
}
```

Comment: not quite, it stops the menu from printing twice but it cancels the Scanner event.

Comment: Why'd it stop the Scanner from reading the input? You have to make this change only on the `while()` line, not anywhere else where you are setting `autoRun` to true or false.

Comment: only changed that line, nothing else.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why that'll prevent the Scanner from working. Could you please provide the output and your inputs in the question.

Comment: If your program is exactly the same as what you have shown above, there is nothing in the program which prevents the input from being read again. Let me compile it locally and run it to see if I can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: well, funny at least. i deleted the last autoRun = true; from the code and the autoRun = false from the beginning and it apparently only loops properly when i don't input something expected from the program.

Comment: See the updated answer. You forgot to scan the new line after scanning the Double value unlike you did after scanning the int. With that fix, your program works as expected.

Comment: there is only one problem: the

`if(credPassCheck.equals("numbers")){
    System.out.print("Number Credential Password: ");
    double credPassNum = e.nextDouble();
}`

block doesn't exist. Its more like:

`if(credPassCheck.equals("numbers")){
        
            System.out.print("Credential Password: ");
            double credPassNum = e.nextDouble();
            e.nextLine();
        }`

Comment: There are no more problems. You have probably not seen my update above.

Comment: nope, sorry, it works now. It probably was a error with the NetBeans compiler and executor, in a .bat file it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that we could help!

Comment: just a last little question, when i finish the code, any good recommendations on where to post it?

Comment: Yep, head over to [StackExchange's CodeReview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get blasted. You'll get some really good suggestions there.